# Send email using OAuth 

Tags: c#, smtp, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I am trying to send an email through gmail using oauth credentials. 
I cannot seem to find any smtp class in the framework, or open source alternatives that work with oauth access token.

I found these references on google developer's website [Gmail IMAP and SMTP using OAuth - Overview](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/) and [Gmail IMAP and SMTP using OAuth - Protocol](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html), but I am not sure who to implement it.

1. Are there any open source classes that support sending emails that are authenticated by oauth credentials?
2. Is there any wrapper that helps write custom smtp calls ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use SmtpClient in the System.Net.Mail namespace.

This Q covers how to do it in detail: [Sending Email via GMail and .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490749/sending-email-via-gmail-and-net-4)